# How to get the first character from a word or a string

Tags: swift4

Say , I have the middlename as follows and I used below code.

```
var firstMiddlename = "Thompson"

let firstCharIndex = firstMiddlename.startIndex

let firstChar = firstMiddlename.index(after: firstCharIndex)
```

Somehow, this is not working. Please show me how to get the first character.

// update:

var firstMiddlename = "Thompson"

let firstCharacter = firstMiddlename.first

let name = MyFirstName + " " + firstCharacter + " " + MyLastName

Error:

Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Character?'

Thanks

Comment: Re "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Character?'"; cast the sub-string in `String(firstCharacter)`.

Comment: @ trojanfoe . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 4.x**

```
var firstMiddlename = "Thompson"

let firstCharcter = firstMiddlename.first

print(firstCharcter) // T
```

And if you want to set of character from first or last. You can use prefix

```
firstMiddlename.prefix(2) // Th
```

And final append string like this

```
let name = "\(MyLastName) \(firstMiddlename.first!) \(MyLastName)"
```

Comment: I encounter error using the code. How to solve it?  I have show the error msg above.

Comment: I have shown the err msg in my update in above. Thanks

Comment: I think you mean String(firstCharacter). this solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes can also write that.

Comment: If you found answer helpful than make it upvote @MilkBottle

Comment: @MilkBottle `let name = "\(MyLastName) \(firstMiddlename.first!) \(MyLastName)"`will crash your app if the middle name is empty. Better to use `firstMiddlename.prefix(1)` that will return an empty string instead of crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `prefix`

For example:

```
let firstChar = firstMiddlename.prefix(1)
```